# How compatible is the new Microsoft edge browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

A Microsoft has launched their new browser, how compatible will it be compared to IE.

I just tried with some of the web sites , feels good at first glance.

Any body faced any technical issue so far in any js, css , html areas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is a list of all the functions compared to other browsers:
[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+Edge,firefox+40,chrome+44)

Comment: That's a good website. Didn't know it existed.